# Can't find correct MySQL via the command line

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

About 3 months ago I installed xampp and I have been using that as my local PHP/MySQL environment.

I now need to import a large database via the command line. I did this once before months ago, successfully, and can't remember how I did it.

I am opening MySQL like this 
Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql

It shows that I have two databases (which is incorrect)

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

When I open up phpmyadmin, here are the databases I have been working with > for a few months now:

screenshot - http://cl.ly/image/2v2B0L0I1v3S

This is where I need to be to upload the large database. This machine is only a few months old and I am fairly certain I have not installed any other instances of MySQL. Can anyone give me some insight on where to look, or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you logged in using the correct user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the import function of phpmysql.  It accepts the same files you would need to use on the command line interface anyway and it will put it into the correct MySQL server (if you happen to have 2).  I'm not familar with Macs and how they list processes but either the user you logged in on the command line with doesnt have adequate permissions or there is a second instace of MySQL on you machine.  You can also look in the processes tab of phpmyadmin to see where the processes are running from.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - Your comment led me to the right place. When I invoked the MySQL command, I had noticed that the user was not root. When I invoked MySQL -u root -p , and then show databases; I was able to see my databases.